# Javascript: "Mouseover" and "mouseout" event handlers work, but "mouseout" doesn't work properly when "mouseover" is replaced by "click"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a dropdown menu on a webpage using JavaScript(not jQuery).
My research has shown only similar issues with images and colors, but the solutions to those problems do not fix my dropdown menu.

When "mouseover" is used to open my dropdown menu in an event handler, the "mouseout" event handler allows me to scroll over my links in the list just fine before the dropdown menu is closed when the "mouseout" event occurs. When "mouseover" is replaced by "click" in the event handler, "mouseout" fires as it leaves the text content of the dropdown button, which does not allow me to move my cursor to items in the dropdown menu.

The links float as inline-block elements to the left of the top of the screen. They are fixed and do not overflow when the screen is resized. The dropdown menu has a dropBtn that is visible while the rest of the dropItem list-items are display: none; using CSS. The JavaScript targets the list-items that are display: none; when the dropBtn fires an event. The list items then gain display: list-item;. When the cursor leaves the navigation it is supposed to give the list-items display: none; again, but display: none; happens too soon when the "click" event is paired with the "mouseout" event.

Does anyone have a way to write this to allow me to click the dropBtn to open the drop menu, allowing me to move my cursor across the links before closing the drop menu with a mouseout event?

```js
let dropMenu = document.querySelector("#dropMenu");
let navList = document.querySelectorAll("#dropMenu li");
let navDrop = document.querySelector("#navDrop");
let listContainer = document.querySelector("#listContainer");
let navItemNumber = navList.length;


function toggleNavOpen() {


  for (let i = 1; i < navItemNumber; i++) {
    navList[i].style.display = "list-item";
  }
  for (let i = 1; i < navItemNumber; i++) {
    navList[i].style.width = "110px";
  }
}


dropMenu.addEventListener("mouseover", toggleNavOpen);
//replace mouseover with click in the previous line, and the 
//code doesn't work properly.


function toggleNavClose() {

  for (let i = 1; i < navItemNumber; i++) {

    navList[i].style.display = "none";

  }
}

dropMenu.addEventListener("mouseout", toggleNavClose);
```

```css
.content {
  clear: both;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 20px 5px 20px;
  padding: 31px 37px;
  background-image: url("../images/logo.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.row {
  float: left;
  overflow: unset;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #d8e9ee;
  width: 100%;
}

.top {
  position: fixed;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 25px 8px 0px 8px;
  padding: 12px 14px;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: 2px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: rgb(11, 12, 36);
  background-color: #f5f5ed;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

.menu:hover {
  margin: 24px 8px 0px 6px;
  border-style: ridge;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px;
  font-size: 1.45em;
  border-radius: .9em;
  /*transition-duration: 250ms;*/
}

#navDrop {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
}

#dropMenu {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: 2px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px;
  color: rgb(11, 12, 36);
  background-color: #f5f5ed;
  border-radius: 1em;
  margin: 25px 8px 0 8px;
}

#dropMenu:hover {
  font-size: 1.45em;
  border-style: ridge;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px;
  margin: 24px 8px 0px 7px;
  border-radius: .9em;
}

.dropBtn {
  padding: 12px 14px;
}

.dropItem {
  display: none;
  padding: 12px 14px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="menu"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="content/tuning.html#tuning">Tuning</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="content/videos.html">Lessons</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="content/tools.html">Tools</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="content/signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="content/signin.html">Sign in</a></li>
  <li id="navDrop">
    <ul id="dropMenu">
      <li class="dropBtn"><a href="#">More</a></li>
      <li class="dropItem"><a href="content/tuning.html#repairs">Repairs</a></li>
      <li class="dropItem"><a href="content/supplies.html">Supplies</a></li>
      <li class="dropItem"><a href="content/pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
      <li class="dropItem"><a href="content/services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li class="dropItem"><a href="content/about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="dropItem"><a href="content/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant CSS to it

Comment: The snippet doesn't have a click event firing for the dropdown. Its different than my issue.

Comment: The snippet is YOUR CODE!!! in snippet format

Comment: I made a comment in my code. it said replace mouseover with click and it stops working. So the code you made a snippet does work. Its when you change the code to have a click event that the code fails.  Also, I added the css but it is mostly irrelevant to the issue but maybe it will give you a better idea of what the page looks like.

Comment: The CSS is of course very important. Next time please click edit, scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and past the css in the css pane like I just did for you. Before it was not clear what to trigger and how.

Comment: I added a class called open and test if it is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this - note I added a class called open

```js
let dropMenu = document.querySelector("#dropMenu");
let navList = document.querySelectorAll("#dropMenu li");
let navDrop = document.querySelector("#navDrop");
let listContainer = document.querySelector("#listContainer");
let navItemNumber = navList.length;


function toggleNav(e) { // called on click AND mouseleave
  const tgt = e.target; // clicked or mouseleave'd object
  const li = document.querySelector(".dropBtn"); 
  if (tgt.id && tgt.id === "dropMenu" && e.type === "mouseleave") {
    li.classList.add("open"); // pretend the li class is open
  }
  const open = li.classList.contains("open"); // is it open?
  [...navList].forEach(nav => nav.classList.toggle("open", !open)); // toggle the class

  if (tgt.tagName === "A" && tgt.closest("li").classList.contains("dropBtn")) {
    li.classList.toggle("open"); // toggle if clicked
  }
}
dropMenu.addEventListener("click", toggleNav);
dropMenu.addEventListener("mouseleave", toggleNav);
```

```css
.content {
  clear: both;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 20px 5px 20px;
  padding: 31px 37px;
  background-image: url("../images/logo.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.row {
  float: left;
  overflow: unset;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #d8e9ee;
  width: 100%;
}

.top {
  position: fixed;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 25px 8px 0px 8px;
  padding: 12px 14px;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: 2px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: rgb(11, 12, 36);
  background-color: #f5f5ed;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

.menu:hover {
  margin: 24px 8px 0px 6px;
  border-style: ridge;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px;
  font-size: 1.45em;
  border-radius: .9em;
  /*transition-duration: 250ms;*/
}

#navDrop {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
}

#dropMenu {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: 2px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px;
  color: rgb(11, 12, 36);
  background-color: #f5f5ed;
  border-radius: 1em;
  margin: 25px 8px 0 8px;
}

#dropMenu:hover {
  font-size: 1.45em;
  border-style: ridge;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px;
  margin: 24px 8px 0px 7px;
  border-radius: .9em;
}

.dropBtn {
  padding: 12px 14px;
}

.dropItem {
  display: none;
  padding: 12px 14px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.open {
  display: list-item;
  width: 110px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="menu"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="content/tuning.html#tuning">Tuning</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="content/videos.html">Lessons</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="content/tools.html">Tools</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="content/signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="content/signin.html">Sign in</a></li>
  <li id="navDrop">
    <ul id="dropMenu">
      <li class="dropBtn"><a href="#">More</a></li>
      <li class="dropItem"><a href="content/tuning.html#repairs">Repairs</a></li>
      <li class="dropItem"><a href="content/supplies.html">Supplies</a></li>
      <li class="dropItem"><a href="content/pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
      <li class="dropItem"><a href="content/services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li class="dropItem"><a href="content/about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="dropItem"><a href="content/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works when clicked on, but then it only closes when clicked on as well. I want it to open with a click and close with a mouseout. Thank you for the snippets, they are helpful.

Comment: Also, for some reason this code you wrote isnt working in chrome for me.

Comment: See update. I test the event type - I wrote the code on Chrome

Comment: I just switched mouseout with mouseleave in my code and it worked. Your example led the way. I like the way you wrote your code. Thank you!

Comment: The wierd thing is, your code isnt working in VS code for me, and still not on chrome. I have no clue why, but the mouseleave did the job for me.

Comment: The snippet is written and tested in Chrome